# Total variation distance

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{X}$ be the input or feature space, let $\mathcal{B}$ be Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathcal{X}$ and $P(\mathcal{X})$ denotes the set of all probability measures on $(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{B})$. Let $P_1, P_2 \in P(\mathcal{X})$, The total variation is defined by
$$\delta(P_1, P_2) = \sup_{A\in \mathcal{B}}|P_1(A)-P_2(A)|$$

I would like to ask for the idea of proving the following lemma,

Let $P_1, P_2 \in P(\mathcal{X})$ and let $\mathcal{F}$ the unit ball in $L^{\infty}(\mathcal{X})$,

$$\mathcal{F}=\{f \in L^{\infty}(\mathcal{X}) | \; ||f||_{\infty} \leq 1\}$$
then we have the following characterization for the total varation distance
$$\delta(P_1, P_2) = \sup_{f\in\mathcal{F}}|\mathbb{E}_{x\sim P_1}f(x) - \mathbb{E}_{x\sim P_2}f(x)|$$

Comment: Which definition of the total variation do you start with?

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker I've added the definition of TV in the content.

Comment: In that case, the standard argument relies on the [Hahn decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn_decomposition_theorem).

Comment: @DRive : Do you have a response to the answer below?

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, but I am still filling in my understanding of the Hahn decomposition. I am not fully able to understand the solution at the moment.

Comment: @DRive : What is the first place that seems unclear to you?

Comment: It may be easier to picture in a discrete, finite setting. There is a set $X^+$ where $P_1$ has higher probability than $P_2$, and a disjoint set $X^-$ where $P_2$ has higher probability than $P_1$. You can convince yourself that either set achieves the supremum in the definition of total variation distance, just by moving one element at a time in or out of $A$. Then consider $f$ which is $1$ on $X^+$ and $-1$ on $X^-$, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\X}{\mathcal X}\newcommand{\B}{\mathcal B}\newcommand{\F}{\mathcal F}\newcommand{\De}{\Delta}\newcommand{\de}{\delta}$Let $\mu:=P_1-P_2$, so that $\mu$ is a finite signed measure. By the [Hahn--Jordan decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn_decomposition_theorem), there exist sets $\X^\pm\in\B$ such that $\X^+\cap\X^-=\emptyset$, $\X^+\cup\X^-=\X$, the functions $\mu^\pm$ defined by the formulas $\mu^+(B):=\mu(B\cap\X^+)$ and $\mu^-(B):=-\mu(B\cap\X^-)$ for $B\in\B$ are (nonnegative) measures, and
\begin{equation}
    \mu=\mu^+-\mu^-. 
\end{equation}

So, for any $f\in\F$,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    \int_\X f\,dP_1-\int_\X f\,dP_2&=\int_\X f\,d\mu \\ 
    &=\int_{\X^+} f\,d\mu+\int_{\X^-} f\,d\mu \\ 
    &=\int_{\X^+} f\,d\mu^+ -\int_{\X^-} f\,d\mu^- \\ 
    &\le\int_{\X^+} 1\,d\mu^+ -\int_{\X^-} (-1)\,d\mu^- \\ 
    &=\mu^+(\X)+\mu^-(\X).  
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Similarly, $\int_\X f\,dP_2-\int_\X f\,dP_1\le\mu^+(\X)+\mu^-(\X)$ and hence
\begin{equation}
    \Big|\int_\X f\,dP_1-\int_\X f\,dP_2\Big|\le\mu^+(\X)+\mu^-(\X),
\end{equation}
with the equality if $f=1_{\X^+}-1_{\X^-}$. So,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\De(P_1,P_2)&:=\sup_{f\in\F}|E_{x\sim P_1}f(x) - E_{x\sim P_2}f(x)| \\ 
&=\max_{f\in\F}\Big|\int_\X f\,dP_1-\int_\X f\,dP_2\Big| \\ 
&=  \mu^+(\X)+\mu^-(\X)=2\mu^+(\X);
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
the latter equality holds because $0=P_1(\X)-P_2(\X)=\mu(\X)=\mu^+(\X)-\mu^-(\X)$, so that $\mu^+(\X)=\mu^-(\X)$.

On the other hand, for any $A\in\B$ we have $P_1(A)-P_2(A)=\mu(A)=\mu^+(A)-\mu^-(A)\le\mu^+(A)\le\mu^+(\X)$ and similarly $P_2(A)-P_1(A)=-\mu(A)=\mu^-(A)-\mu^+(A)\le\mu^-(A)\le\mu^-(\X)=\mu^+(\X)$, so that $|P_1(A)-P_2(A)|\le\mu^+(\X)$, with the equality if $A=\X^+$. So,
\begin{equation}
    \de(P_1,P_2)=\mu^+(\X)=\frac12\,\De(P_1,P_2).
\end{equation}
(You had the factor $\frac12$ missing.)

---

*Remark:* Here $\B$ does not have to be a Borel $\sigma$-algebra; it can be any $\sigma$-algebra over any set $\X$.